# Recover an $L^1$ Integrand by Partial Differentiation

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Denote by $m$ the 2-dimensional Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Let $f$ be an element of $L^1(m)$ that takes only nonnegative values. Define $F : \mathbb{R}^2 \longrightarrow [0,\infty)$ by $\displaystyle F(x,y) = \int\limits _{(-\infty,x] \times (-\infty,y]} fdm$, where $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$. Is there a counterexample to the statement that $\partial _2\partial _1F = f$ a.e.? Or this is actually a true statement?

Comment: I think yes. The Lebesgue integral of a measureable function is absolutely continuous. Your $F$ is essentially a CDF, and the condition to extract the pdf from a distribution function is precisely absolute continuity, and way you do this once absolute continuity is established is indeed differentiation.

Answer (score 0):

Lemma 1 in Serrin J. (1961), On the Differentiability of Functions of Several Real Variables. *Archive for Rational Mechanics and Analysis*, 7, 359–372.